# Assign values to first row of matrix in C++

Tags: c++, boost, matrix

I am very new to C++ programming and I am trying to figure out a concise way to assign values to the first row of an matrix. I am using the boost c++ library.  The following is a small snippet of my code that I believe is necessary to illustrate my problem.

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> matrix;
matrix T_zone(boost::extents[2000][10])
```

I want to assign the first row of the T_zone matrix the value of 400. I realize I could do this with a for loop, but is there a better way?  Like in python, I could easily set the first row of the array with `T_zone[0] = 400`.

Comment: Do you want all the slots to have the same value or only the first?

Comment: All the slots in the first row.  So I want T_zone[0][0], T_zone[0][1], T_zone[0][2]...T_zone[0][9] all to be 400.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not do it with a single line of code. You have to use a for loop. Correct me if I am wrong.